# How can I call a module function inside Enum.map without getting an "Undefined reference" error?

Tags: elixir

I have a simple module containing a single function:

```
defmodule Funcs do

  def double(x) do
    x*2
  end

end
```

When I start `iex` with the file name as argument, I can call the function just fine:

```
iex(5)> Funcs.double(3)
6
```

But when I try to use it in `Enum.map`, I get an `undefined function` error:

```
iex(2)> Enum.map([1,2,3,4], Funcs.double)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Funcs.double/0
    Funcs.double()
```

whereas if I just use an analogous anonymous function, everything works as expected:

```
iex(6)> Enum.map([1,2,3,4], fn(x) -> x*2; end)
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

How can I use a module function (unsure whether that's the correct term) as an argument to Enum.map?

Comment: I added a link to the docs for the `&` special form to my answer, sorry I didn't before but I was on mobile.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The syntax for capturing non-anonymous functions uses `&function/arity`.

In your example:

```
Enum.map([1,2,3,4], &Funcs.double/1)
```

You can read more about the capture syntax (which is very common in Elixir) in [the docs for the `&` special form](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1).